# Linked List - how to tail insert without moving head node

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

So am running into a problem. I know what it is. i just can't figure out a way to solve it with what am allowed to do..

first here is my tail insert function

```
Status append(MY_QUEUE queue, int item)
{
    Node_ptr temp;
    Head_ptr head = (Head_ptr) queue;

    //create a new node

    temp = (Node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return FAILURE;
    }

    temp->data = item;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head->head == NULL){
        head->head = temp;
    }
    else{
        while(head->head->next) {
            head->head = head->head->next;
        }
        head->head->next = temp;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

as you see. its simple. if the head node is null. it adds the new node to head. if not. it keeps moving head until it reaches null and then it adds the node. thats the problem. am moving head node pointer which i am not supposed to do. but i cant seem to think of an another way to do it. since am passing in a MY_QUEUE. i will include the header files and the declarations to understand what these are.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    Node_ptr next;

};

struct head_node;
typedef struct head_node Head_node;
typedef Head_node *Head_ptr;

struct head_node
{
    struct my_queue_public methods;
    Node_ptr head;
};

void destroy(MY_QUEUE queue);
Status append(MY_QUEUE queue, int item);
Status service(MY_QUEUE queue);
int* front(MY_QUEUE queue);
Bool empty(MY_QUEUE stack);

void init_functions(MY_QUEUE queue)
{
    //queue->destroy = destroy;
    queue->empty = empty;
    queue->service = service ;
    queue->append = append;
    queue->front = front;
}
MY_QUEUE my_queue_init_default(void)
{
    Head_ptr head;
    head = malloc(sizeof(Head_node));

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        head->head = NULL;
        init_functions((MY_QUEUE)head);
    }
    return (MY_QUEUE)head;
}
```

The insert tail function is the append function. I can't change my parameters or what i return. i simply have to change whats inside the function.

MY_QUEUE is a public version of struct Node.

here is the header file

```
#include "status.h"
struct my_queue_public;
typedef struct my_queue_public* MY_QUEUE;

struct my_queue_public
{
    void(*destroy)(MY_QUEUE* phMy_queue);
    Status(*service)(MY_QUEUE hMy_queue);
    Status(*append)(MY_QUEUE hMy_queue, int item);
    Bool(*empty)(MY_QUEUE hMy_queue);
    int* (*front)(MY_QUEUE hMy_queue);
};

MY_QUEUE my_queue_init_default(void);
```

By the way this is a queue. add at the end. get items from the front. to sum it up the head is moving and i lose the nodes. i know how to avoid it but the only way i know is to change what i pass in. instead of a MY_QUEUE. i'd pass a MY_QUEUE*. is there an another way to do it with what i have

DESTROY FUNCTION

```
    void destroy(MY_QUEUE queue)
{

    Head_ptr head = (Head_ptr)queue;

    Node_ptr tmp;

    if (head->head == NULL) {

        return;
    }


    while (head->head !=NULL){
        tmp = head->head;
        head->head = head->head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }

    head->head = NULL;
}
```

Comment: There are a zillion linked list implementations that work very well; why write your own?  Or, if you really want/need to write your own, why not look at one of the existing implementations?

Comment: i didn't write my own this is given to me by my teacher so i have to use this skeleton.

Comment: Store the `head` in a temporary `head_ptr` and play with that.

Comment: ^ You realize am already doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> thats the problem. am moving head node pointer which i am not
>   supposed to do. but i cant seem to think of an another way to do it.

You can use a temporary variable `tail` to track the link, rather than moving head node,

```
    Node_ptr tail;
    if (head->head == NULL){
        head->head = temp;
    }
    else{
        //while(head->head->next) {
        //  head->head = head->head->next;
        //  }
        //head->head->next = temp;
        tail = head->head;
        while(tail->next) {
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        tail->next = temp;
    }
```

For the destroy func,

```
//void destroy(MY_QUEUE queue);
void destroy(MY_QUEQUE *p_queue);//change to this 
                                 //to keep consistent in struct my_queue_public

 void destroy(MY_QUEUE *p_queue)
 {
    Head_ptr head;
    Node_ptr tmp;

   if(p_queue == NULL){
     return;
   }

   if((head = (Head_ptr)*p_queue) == NULL){
     return;
   }    

   if (head->head == NULL) {
     return;
   }

   while (head->head !=NULL){
      tmp = head->head;
      head->head = head->head->next;
      free(tmp);
   }

   free(head);
  }
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. can i get a tip on the destroy function.

Comment: Could you provide your destroy function code just like the good try of  `append`?:)

Comment: lol ok i will edit it into the original post. its crashing. am not a genius in this field but here is my best try.

Comment: Oh, there was another thing. In `struct my_queue_public `, it is `void(*destroy)(MY_QUEUE* phMy_queue);` which demands a `MY_QUEUE pointer` parameter. But in the implementation of `void destroy(MY_QUEUE queue)`, it was passed in a `MY_QUEUE` parameter (not a pointer). That's the reason.

Comment: its still crashing. honestly i have no clue why

Comment: you comment  `//queue->destroy = destroy;`, did you enable it? I have tested your code, it shall be OK:)

Comment: yes. visual studio is telling me what is failing. the free(tmp); part. stack view is showing me that tmp has a value in memory. which is weird. shouldn't it be NULL. and next and data are not defined. how could that be.

Comment: I have pasted my code based on your destroy func, you may try again. And remember to change the definition of `destroy` to keep it consistent. Then call it like `q->destroy(&q);`

Comment: that is what am doing.

Comment: When the `free(tmp)` failed, it means the memory might have been corrupted  by some operation before you exec `free`. So, if it still has problem, you may paste all your code include main( ) function for diagnosis reference if you'd like.

Comment: i will actually explain the program to you and i will post it after this. the program basically supposed to calculate how many trips a ferry takes to move cars from the left side to the right side. vice versa. so i have two queues with cars.  i enter how many cars and which side which cars are on and their length and the ferry length. .

Comment: now one by one i store the car lengths in their respective ques. left and right in their own nodes in the list. and i keep tracking how much length left and deleting the nodes. now by the end of the program before the destroy function. i am supposed to have all the nodes. except the Head_ptr node freed. but it which if they werent the program wouldn't work at all. and the program is working which means that all the nodes but the head_ptr node are deleted basically. the destroy function is basically to delete the head_ptr node and the list if things werent entered correctly there were leftovers

Comment: Ok main is up there with the destroy function

Comment: Wow, a huge project. Firstly, You can write a unit test to make sure that MY_QUEUE data structures works well by a minimal test set includes some operation sequences , e.g. "append 3 nodes -> remove 1 node ->destroy" etc. The `append`/`remove` is also memory related. The mistake from them will probably result in `free()` failure in `destroy` later. Secondly, after build the infrastructure--MY_QUEQUE, then you can apply it as a tool to your project. Otherwise, you could be confused when there was problem, it is because of data structure or the problem resolving logic itself? Hope it helps.

Comment: i figured out hte problem. am not dereferencing the MY_QUEUE. even though the cast should automatically do it but it all works now.

Comment: Good to hear that! Yes, we should take care of the casting , dereferencing,  and so on, which is error prone.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are using the struct `Node` as the data structure for you queue. Why not using a more dedicated version?

```
typedef struct queue_struct {
    Node * head;
    Node * tail;
} * MY_QUEUE;
```

And now, well, that's it. You don't have to run all over the list in order to add at the end. The only problem is that you'll have to keep `tail` as well as `head` up when inserting (and removing), as following.

```
Status append(MY_QUEUE queue, int item)
{
    Node_ptr temp;

    // create a new node
    temp = (Node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return FAILURE;
    }

    temp->data = item;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (queue->head == NULL){
        queue->head = temp;
        queue->tail = temp;
    }
    else {
        queue->tail->next = temp;
        queue->tail = temp;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what structure did you replace with that? and how do i keep track of the tail in that case? MY_QUEUE does not have data or next. its a public version. its not complete as it needs the Struct Node to work. am not sure how familiar are you with opaque objects

Comment: I've added an example of how to append a new element (i.e., insert at the tail), keeping track of the tail. As you can see, it is not difficult at all.